# How does styling work in Material UI to change the color of the focus label?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to learn how to style with JSS. I wanted to change the color of the label in an InputLabel when it is focused. I eventually got it to work the following code but I don't understand why it works:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select, } from '@material-ui/core/'

const styles = theme => ({
  inputLabel: {
    '&$focused': {
      color: 'red',
    },
  },
  focused: {
  },
})

class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return(
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel className={classes.inputLabel} FormLabelClasses={ classes }>Select</InputLabel>
          <Select/>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Test.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Test)
```

Specifically, I don't understand why I can't just set the color to red in the outer `focused` field. I am also not sure I understand what `&$focused` does -- I thought that just references the outer `focused` field but if so why can't I just set the outer `focused` field to be `{ color: 'red' }`? I tried that and it doesn't work. Furthermore, if I just remove the outer `focused` field, it stops setting the color to red! Why is it necessary? I also don't understand what the point of passing `classes` to `FormLabelClasses` is -- again if I remove it, it doesn't cause the focused label to be red.

Answer (score 1):

`InputLabel` is a controller-wrapper for `FormLabel`. It reads the context from the `FormControl` to apply styles depending on the variant used. It uses `classes` for additional styling logic. That's why you have to explicitly pass classes that are only meant for `FormLabel`.

To answer the question why you can't simply apply the color to `focused` read "Internal states" under https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes.

You have to define it with an empty object in order for JSS to pick it up as a className and allow nested references to that rule. This is also explained in the linked section.

Hope that answers everything sufficiently. If the documentation is unclear you can always open an issue or file a PR over at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui.

Comment: I don't want to repeat every implementation detail to you that you can't just read from the actual source. If you still have suggestions how to simplify the API feel free to open an issue. Focus is something the browser sets. It's not meant to be controlled.